# Why is this PDOException not caught?

Tags: php

I have this little snippet that connects to sql server using PDO, and it fails because my server is down (which is correct, it's the scenario I want to test). However, the exception is not caught!

```
$dsn = "sqlsrv:Server=$host,$port;Database=$database";
$conn = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


$works = false;
try {
    $works = ($conn->exec('SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES') !== false);
}
catch (\PDOException $e) {
}
echo "works? " . ($works ? 'yes' : 'no') . "\n";
```

The output I get in console:

```
➜  backend git:(dev) ✗ php mssql-pdo-test.php
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HYT00]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login
timeout expired in /path/mssql-pdo-test.php:10
Stack trace:
#0 /path/mssql-pdo-test.php(10): PDO->__construct()
#1 {main}
  thrown in /path/mssql-pdo-test.php on line 10
```

Comment: Isn't that failure coming from the instantiation of the PDO connection which is NOT inside of your try/catch block?

Comment: The exception is thrown by the `new PDO` not the `exec()`.

Comment: I feel quite stupid, but I knew it had to be simple... I didn't realise that "new PDO" already actively did something, but of course it does make sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the exception is thrown outside the try / catch block here:

```
$conn = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Comment: I feel quite stupid, but I knew it had to be simple... I didn't realise that "new PDO" already actively did something, but of course it does make sense. Thanks!